# VUEX state is not loading up if a page is visited directly

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am currently having an issue with retrieving states depending on the page in which someone first visits.

Right now, I have got VUEX setup to "fetchUsers" from app.vue. The VUEX Module looks like so;

```
import db from '@/firebase/init'

const state = {
  user: {
    loggedIn: false,
    data: null
  },
  userInfo: null
}

const getters = {
  user (state) {
    return state.user
  },
  userInfo (state) {
    return state.userInfo
  }
}

const actions = {
  fetchUser ({ commit }, user) {
    commit('SET_LOGGED_IN', user !== null)
    if (user) {
      commit('SET_USER', {
        email: user.email,
        uid: user.uid
      })
    } else {
      commit('SET_USER', null)
    }
  },
  fetchUserInfo ({ commit }) {
    if (state.user.loggedIn === true) {
      state.userInfo = null
      let userRef = null
      const ref = db.collection('Users')
        .where('user_id', '==', state.user.data.uid)
      ref.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
          userRef = doc.data()
          userRef.id = doc.id
        })
      }).then(() => {
        commit('SET_USER_INFO', userRef)
      })
    }
  }
}

const mutations = {
  SET_LOGGED_IN (state, value) {
    state.user.loggedIn = value
  },
  SET_USER (state, data) {
    state.user.data = data
  },
  SET_USER_INFO (state, userRef) {
    state.userInfo = userRef
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

And, I initialize it in my main.js as such;

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  store.dispatch('fetchUser', user).then(() => {
    store.dispatch('fetchUserInfo')
  })
})
```

If a user visits my home page, then goes elsewhere on the site, everything plays nicely. However if a user visits, lets say "project page" then it shows "_vm.userInfo is null". (or/also this.$store.getters.userInfo is null)
Even though, I am using a mapGetter just like I do on the home page to grab userInfo from the store.

What is it i am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably because the user data is not fetched when the page is loaded? You seem to be only fetching it when the auth state has changed.

Comment: Im not sure, because neither of these pages fetch. But yet one will retrieve the data whilst the other will not, despite both being the same "level" within the site?

Answer (score 0):

When the user visits any other page, the `onAuthStateChanged` function gets invoked by `firebase` and you've called store.dispatch in the `onAuthStateChanged` function. You can fix this by using the proper `store` variable.